# injecting bean instances in list in using spring with java config

Tags: spring

I am trying to inject multiple instances of a same bean in a list of same bean type using java config in spring IOC . But while printing the values of instances in list object it is showing for only one , I m not getting what's wrong with this code. But I am not getting desired output. One more thing I have tried by removing the addition of 1st instance in list yet it is showing data for that only. my code is like this (I m using Eclipse Kepler)

JAVA Config code

```
package SprLab8InjectOfCollectionAnno;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class springconfigLab8 {
@Bean
public List<String> emails()
{
List<String> emails=new ArrayList();
emails.add("Aman@dittu");
emails.add("Dileep@dittu");
emails.add("Mohit@dittu");
emails.add("Sumit@dittu");
return emails;

}

@Bean
public Set<Long> phones()
{
Set<Long> phones=new LinkedHashSet();
phones.add(1111l);
phones.add(2222l);
phones.add(3333l);
phones.add(4444l);
return phones;

}

@Bean(name="refs")
public Map<String,Long> references()
{
Map<String,Long> ref=new LinkedHashMap();
ref.put("aa", 11l);
ref.put("bb", 22l);
ref.put("cc", 33l);
ref.put("dd", 44l);
return ref;
}

@Bean(name="props")
public Properties myproperties()
{
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.put("aa", 11l);
prop.put("bb", 22l);
prop.put("cc", 33l);
prop.put("dd", 44l);
return prop;
}

@Bean
public Address address()
{
return new Address("Bangalore","J.P.Nagar","Karnataka");
}

@Bean 
public Account account()
{
Account acc=new Account();
acc.setAccno(11);
acc.setAtype("Saving Account");
acc.setBal(10000.0);
return acc;
}


@Bean(name="accounts")
public List<Account> accounts()
{
List<Account> accounts=new ArrayList<Account>();
Account acc2=new Account();
acc2.setAccno(12);
acc2.setAtype("Saving Account");
acc2.setBal(30000.0);
accounts.add(account());//if I am commenting this line then also it is 
                        //showing output for this line only.
accounts.add(acc2);// this line is not working 
return accounts;
}

@Bean(name="cust")
public Customer custom(Address addr)
{
Customer custs=new Customer(101,"Dileep","Dileep@dittu",9999l);
custs.setAddress(addr);
return custs;
}

}
/* expected output for Account list is 
 11 Saving Account 10000
 12 Saving Account 30000 

 but I m getting 11 Saving Account 10000
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @DwB .... but I am not asking about scope .... If I use prototype how will it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple instanced of the same bean if your scope is singleton. Singleton is the default scope

Comment: yes absolutely @Jacob.... but we can create beans with different id of same type.... I mean for Ex... <bean id="a1" class="A"> and <bean id="a2" class="A">  . It is possible U can do that.